# CPU usage messuring?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vps, performance-monitoring, cpu-usage

I have a Windows 2003 cloud server and I did like to checkout the current usage of cpu and memory of 2 applications I have currently running but I am not sure of what would be the right tools to check these out on a VPS server.

What tools should I consider using to verify CPU usage at the current moment, not statistic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could monitor the **Processor** object in `prefmon`. You can get really good info from that. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749850.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can uh, hit CTRL+SHIFT+ESC and go to "processes" then sort by cpu usage.

Comment: that is what I currently do hence why I am looking for a more specific way to get data from current running application that is more reliable than that.

Answer (score -1):

There are programs that monitor Apache specifically and generate graphs and stuff. Some are free, others paid-for. Here's a free one: http://apache-monitor.com/downloads/hslab-http-monitor-lite.exe they charge for the premium one. This program really only is a glorified "server-status" page. Feel free to try though, or google for more... http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=apache+monitor&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e03806ca3058f972&biw=1366&bih=651